# Battery: uncharging?

Tags: ubuntu, battery, battery-life

I have a Lenovo Laptop (G470). My OS is Ubuntu.

Five minutes ago my computer said that only two minutes were necessary in order to have the battery fully charged. Right now the indicator says that I should wait ten minutes. What is happening? Is my battery or charger damaged? Is my battery uncharging?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on what you're doing it could just be a change in the wattage usage. If your graphics had to kick it up for some process your laptop might take a bit longer to finish charging. Or the estimation was slow to update for things that happened earlier. If you start seeing instances where your battery says it has 10 minutes left to charge for a period of 45 minutes, then it's time to look at the hardware.

Comment: @iamwpj: Thanks for your answer. Could you write this comment as an answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being totally sure, I would guess, this is to guarantee a long living battery.

Your charging controller is discharging and recharging your battery at the very top (about 98%) of its capacity. This prevents some issues (which I don't remember), which might shorten your battery life.

It seems legit that Ubuntu doesn't "know" about that and is just interpreting the raw numbers.

Comment: This. If your battery is >90%, it's as good as charged. If it's low then the charging circuits might bring it up to 100%, but it's very bad to keep it at 100%, so it'll bounce between 90% and 100% after that.

Comment: @DarthAndroid: Actually, my battery does not bounce; it sits still at 100% (and it is connected, using the charger, to electricity right now).